# Js для обновления одного из div по кнопке

Tags: javascript

Мне пришлось поменять все iframe на div, и теперь там табы с div, которые с помощью скрипта тянут с сервера картинки. Мне нужны кнопки, при нажатии на которые определенный див, чья кнопка была нажата, обновит свое содержимое, т.е. получит новую картинку.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Там должен быть какой-то скрипт, опять же, но я нахожу лишь странные, которые предлагают не то или обновляют все.

Comment:   может, ajax

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src='secpic.php?'+Math.random(); return false;"><img id="captcha" src="secpic.php" border="0" /></a>

скажите же, что это бабуйня и не по теме? или я дура все же и такой вариант сработал бы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доброго времени суток.

Есть вариант решить эту задачу через jQuery. 
Для начала создадим **php** файлик с содержанием нашего дива, назовем его например info.php

**info.php:**

```
<?php
$img = "<img src='img.png' alt='' />"; 
echo $img;
?>
```

Далее создаем еще файлик который будет видеть наш юзер, тут же подключаем библиотеку jQuery

**page.html:**

```
 <script text='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#refresh').click(function(){
        $.post('info.php', {refresh:'refresh'}, function success(data){
          $('#info').html(data);
        });
        return false;
      });

    });
  </script>
  <body>
    <div id='info'><?php include 'info.php';?></div>
    <a href='' id='refresh'>Обновить DIV</a>
  </body>
```

Теперь можете изменять значение `$img` нажимать на кнопИчку и будет обновляться.

Answer (score 1):

Дайте дивам атрибут `data-place`, а кнопкам атрибут `data-target`. Будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<div data-place="my-place">Content</div>
<a data-target="my-place" href="#">Action</a>
```

Ну и заскриптуйте след. образом:

```
   var actions = {
      'my-place':function($place){
           alert('any action for my-place');
      },
      'second-place':function($place){
           alert('any action for second-place');
      }
   }

   var $buttons = $('[data-target]');
   $buttons.click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var $this = $(this);
       var thisTarget = $this.attr('data-target');
       var $thisPlace = $('[data-place="'+thisTarget+'"]');
       if ($thisPlace.length && actions[thisTarget]) {
            actions[thisTarget]($thisPlace);
       }
   });
```

Примерчик: http://jsfiddle.net/4nnk38c0/

Answer (score 0):

В общем, если кто-то будет искать, то тут выше оч. интересные примеры, которые, к сожалению, мою задачу не решили. Оставлю здесь свое решение, возможно, кривое, но все же рабочее:

Задача: на странице 4 блока div, обернутых в табы; необходимо у каждого таба сделать кнопку, чтобы при нажатии на которую осуществлялось обновление ТОЛЬКО блока div. На странице висит полный скрипт:

```
<script type='text/javascript'><!--
function refreshIt() {
if (!document.images) return;
var date = new Date();
document.images['MyCam'].src = 'http://URLwebsite.ru/camera/cam0.jpg?' + date.getTime();
setTimeout('refreshIt()',3000); 
}

setTimeout('refreshIt()',5000); 
//--></script>
```

Который подгружает фотки с сервера онлайн (камера фотает - сайт получает фотки).

Дальше стоит еще один скрипт для вывода отдельной каждой камеры:

```
<div class="camera2">
<script type='text/javascript'>
var d = new Date();
document.write("<img id='cam2' src='http://URLwebsite.ru/camera/cam2.jpg?"+d.getTime()+"' width='800' height='450' >");
</script>
</div>
```

В src здесь указан путь к той камере, вывод которой нужен.

Ну и сама кнопка:

```
<input class="newbottoncam" type="button" value="обновить" onclick="d = new Date();document.getElementById('cam2').src = 'http://URLwebsite.ru/camera/cam2.jpg?' + d.getTime(); "/>
```

Ну и, сопсна, все. Это решило мою задачу. 
Вполне вероятно, что это чушь и адекваты так не делают, но оно вполне работает, и заказчик ничего против не имеет.